# Filter based on value for each value in second column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my input table which has distinct events for each site.

| Event | Site |
| --- | --- |
| R1 | Site A |
| R2 | Site A |
| R3 | Site A |
| R4 | Site A |
| R1 | Site B |
| R2 | Site B |
| R3 | Site B |
| R1 | Site C |
| R2 | Site C |
| R3 | Site C |
| R4 | Site C |
| R1 | Site D |
| R2 | Site D |

I am trying to classify sites based on the event occurrence. From the above input table I want to get answers like

- Sites having R4 events --> Site A and Site C

| R4 occurrence sites |
| --- |
| Site A |
| Site C |

- Sites not having R4 events --> Site B and Site C

| R3 and below occurrence sites |
| --- |
| Site B |
| Site C |

- Sites having only R2 or R1 events --> Site D

| R1 and R2 only occurrence sites |
| --- |
| Site D |

I have tried using

To get Sites having R4 events

```
select site where event = 'R4'
```

To get Sites not having R4 events

```
select site where event not in ('R4')
```

To get Sites having only R2 or R1 events

```
select site where event not in ('R4','R3')
```

I also tried using count approach and it gives me results but I cannot use them as some times all events occur for a site except the first one, so it will not be a correct result.

Comment: Please actually show your desired results in addition to explaining them.

Comment: I have updated the question to show actual desired results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general approach for finding sites matching a set of events, e.g. for events `R2`, `R3`, and `R4`:

```sql
SELECT Site
FROM yourTable
WHERE Event IN ('R2', 'R3', 'R4')
GROUP BY Site
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Event) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get Sites having R4 events (*may also have other/non-R4 events*):

```
select distinct site from yourtable where event = 'R4'
```

To get Sites not having R4 events (*but they must have other events*)

```
select distinct site from yourtable where event not in ('R4')
```

To get Sites having only R2 or R1 events (*they should not have other events*)

```
select distinct site 
from yourtable yta 
where event in ('R2','R1')
and not exists (select * 
                from yourtable ytb
                where yta.site=ytb.site 
                and ytb.event not in ('R2','R1')
               )
```